# bounds on parameters of hypergeometric function $_2F_1$

Tags: hypergeometric-function

The hypergemoetric function $_2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ happens to be the primitive of a well known function in astroparticle physics. [Result integration by WolframAlpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69dLT.gif)

In my work, this object is part of more complex function, which is minimized by varying the values of the parameters $a,b,c$.

The question is: for $z<0$, what are the bounds on the parameters $a,b,c$ for $_2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ to be positive definite?
Thank you very much for your comments and help.

Comment: Nothing? I realise that, perhaps, it's not a standard mathematical question, but I would just need a pointer to some paper or web page which addresses my query or where I could find hints. Thank you

Comment: At the least, the hypergeometric function will be positive definite for all $0\le b\le c$. This is obvious from the integral representation.